# Can you create multiple ElasticsearchCrudRepositories in one app?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have two different ElasticsearchCrudRepository interfaces such as:

```
public interface SomeRepository extends ElasticsearchCrudRepository<SomeDao, String> {}

public interface AnotherRepository extends ElasticsearchCrudRepository<AnotherDao, String> {}
```

In my configuration I have something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.something")
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.something.repos")
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean
    public Client client() {
        InetSocketTransportAddress address = new InetSocketTransportAddress(
            new InetSocketAddress('1.2.3.4',9300)
        );
        return TransportClient.builder().build().addTransportAddress(address);
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
       return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
    }
}
```

What I want to do is have the SomeRepository interface connect to server 1.2.3.4 while the AnotherRepository interface connect to a different server, say 5.6.7.8. Is this possible?

I know I could create a second elasticsearchTemplate() method (with a unique name of course) and create a client to 5.6.7.8 but than I would have to inject ElasticsearchTemplate into some Service class and use it instead of using AnotherRepository. I can do this if I must but I prefer using Repositories.

### UPDATE:

Still can't find anything about this anywhere. The lack of documentation for Spring Data ES is unfortunate. I can only seem to find answers for the most basic and trivial cases, which doesn't necessary translate to the real world.

Can anybody point me to a working example of how to use SimpleElasticsearchRepository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be a way to do this. Had to create two different classes that both extend ElasticsearchTemplate and then in the Java config pass in the appropriate Client.